# Why does my ADO Resultset only give me one row when using a PreparedStatement to call a StoredProcedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to query a MySQL database from VBA in Excel by means of a stored procedure with some parameters. My problem is that I only get a maximum of one row in my (ADO) resultset. After hours of searching and troubleshooting I have given up. I've done a lot of research online (of course also on SO as there seem to be a lot of related issues, but none of which is mine - as far as I have seen). I can already inform you what does / does not work:

- I see a lot about DAO ResultSets where the `rs.moveLast` has not been called. However, I'm using an ADO resultset, so this is not the problem.
- When I use a `SELECT * FROM some_table`, everything works fine. It is specifically the StoredProcedure call that gives me headaches. :)
- the parameters passed are valid. When I change them, I do see a different (and correct) result, though just one record. (the SP also check the validity and will change them when empty). I have even implemented special Debug stored procedures and a logging table in the database to log the passed parameters and the way they are handled. All is fine there.
- when I run the same SP manually with the same parameters, I get 3 records.
- I have changed the `CursorLocation` via the `ADODB.Connection` object to `adUseClient` and I've tried different means of retreiving the resultset (via the `ADODB.ResultSet.Open` method, via the `ADODB.Connection` object, via the PreparedStatement). The result stays the same. The `CursorType` is `adOpenStatic` (With a different CursorType, the `recordCount` would give me -1).
- I have checked for multiple result sets (there shouldn't be any) and there are none extra.

In an attempt to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example I've created a new sample Stored Procedure with some testdata, which gives me exactly the same results (i.e. only one row of the table that I would get running the query in HeidySQL or MySQL Workbench):

for instance:
When I enter "S8" in B2 (without the quotes), I should expect three rows - on a new sheet in the same workbook (in line with the data set given below, the result should be: {{S8, apple, red}, {S8, grapes, white}, {S8, banana, yellow}}). Instead, I only get {S8, grapes, white} - strangely enough, this would be the middle record in both SQL clients?

```vb
    Option Explicit

Enum enums 'necessary because of late binding
    adUseClient = 3 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursorlocationenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adCmdStoredProc = 4 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtypeenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adVarChar = 200 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adParamInput = 1 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameterdirectionenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
End Enum

Sub excelmysql()

Dim conn            As Object
Dim spCommand       As Object
Dim param1          As Object
Dim rs              As Object

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set spCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set param1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" _
          & ";SERVER=" & credentials.getServer _
          & ";DATABASE=" & credentials.getDB _
          & ";UID=" & credentials.getUsername _
          & ";PWD=" & credentials.getPassword

' Set spCommand = New ADODB.Command
spCommand.Prepared = True
spCommand.CommandText = "`testProc`"
spCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
spCommand.CommandTimeout = 30
spCommand.ActiveConnection = conn

Set param1 = spCommand.CreateParameter("inputCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, Range("B1").Value)

spCommand.Parameters.Append param1

Set rs = spCommand.Execute()
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

To be complete, here is my SQL SP (which runs just fine):

To define a testing table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
    `someCode` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `text` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `color` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
)
COMMENT='testTable meant for testing'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

To fill the testing table:

```sql
INSERT INTO db.`testTable`
  (`someCode`, `text`, `color`)
VALUES
  ('S8', 'apple', 'red'),
  ('S8', 'banana', 'yellow'),
  ('PB', 'car', 'black'),
  ('S8', 'grapes', 'white'),
  ('TR', 'car', 'purple'),
  ('PB', 'car', 'orange');
```

and finally, to add a Stored Procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `testProc`(IN `inputCode` VARCHAR(2))

    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'test procedure'

    BEGIN

    DECLARE validCode varchar(1);
    SET validCode = IF((COALESCE(inputCode, '') = '') OR (inputCode = '0'), 'N', 'Y');

    SELECT * FROM db.`testTable`
    WHERE (`someCode` LIKE if(validCode = 'Y', inputCode, '%'))
    ORDER BY `color` ASC;

    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/IJJG73450)

I'm grateful for any help, since I'm at a loss.

Please find an alternative way of retrieving the rows (which does not change the outcome unfortunately):

```
Option Explicit

Enum enums 'necessary because of late binding
    adUseClient = 3 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursorlocationenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adOpenStatic = 3 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortypeenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adCmdStoredProc = 4 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtypeenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adVarChar = 200 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
    adParamInput = 1 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameterdirectionenum?view=sqlallproducts-allversions
End Enum

Sub excelmysql()

Dim conn            As Object
Dim spCommand       As Object
Dim param1          As Object
Dim rs              As Object

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set spCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set param1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" _
          & ";SERVER=" & credentials.getServer _
          & ";DATABASE=" & credentials.getDB _
          & ";UID=" & credentials.getUsername _
          & ";PWD=" & credentials.getPassword

' Set spCommand = New ADODB.Command
spCommand.Prepared = True
spCommand.CommandText = "`testProc`"
spCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
spCommand.CommandTimeout = 30
spCommand.ActiveConnection = conn

Set param1 = spCommand.CreateParameter("inputCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, Range("B1").Value)

spCommand.Parameters.Append param1

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic

On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
If (MsgBox("This will clear Sheet: ""test"" in the activeWorkbook if it exists. Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNoCancel + vbExclamation, "Delete Sheet test?") = vbYes) Then
    Sheets("test").Delete
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "User cancelled execution. Please rename your sheet 'test' to something else if it exists and try again.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Execution stopped"
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rs = spCommand.Execute()
Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "test"

Dim row As Long
Dim i As Long

row = 1
rs.moveLast
rs.moveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        If (row = 1) Then
            Sheets("test").Cells(row, i + 1) = rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
        Else
            Sheets("test").Cells(row, i + 1) = rs.Fields.Item(i).Value
        End If
    Next
    If (row > 1) Then
        rs.moveNext
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop

' ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!

Cheers,
Niels

Comment: i would start by removing the "abuse" code to see if that makes anny difference.  If that does not work  or you already tryed that see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also i saw the query `SELECT * FROM kis_bi.SA.KIS0010 LIMIT 15"` using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not make sense as defined by ANSI/ISO SQL standards a SQL table/resultset does **not** have a fixed order.

Comment: @Raymond and Parfait, thank you both for your help. I'll need to give it a try tomorrow, since I cannot access this from home, however, I may already have some answers. The use of LIMIT 15 without the ORDER BY is indeed not very useful. However, this was merely to prove that a "regular" select statement did work (and also, to make sure that I indeed knew I only saw 1 row, instead of a full set (in answer to the comment of Parfait). I have looked at the variables during the debugging session in VBA, which shows only one record, I've dumped the RS into an array, which again, gives me one record.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I've tried your suggestion to bypass the SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT lines, however, unfortunately it does not make any difference. I've also used the Range.CopyFromRecordset methode to dump the recordset into a range with the same results. One line for the SP, 15 lines for the regular select statement.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. It gives me the exact same behaviour. Hopefully someone knows the answer!

Comment: @parfait, I've clarified the expected results and the results I get. I've also corrected some remainders from the original post where I would have gotten 180 results. Right now, I would expect to see three rows, instead I see one.

Comment: Your issue is curious to me. Try the following: 1) Try adding sheet before running query and do not use ActiveSheet but actual named worksheet (isolate GUI appliaciton issues); 2) Instead of `CopyFromRecordset`, loop through your recordset with `Do While NOT rs.EOF`; 3) Add a `rs.MoveLast: rs.MoveFirst` before dumping recordset.

Comment: Hi Parfait, thank you for your added demo setup! I've already tried all the thing you suggested. If it's considered helpful, I can post that particular code too. However, no change in behaviour. My hunch is that it is somehow connected to CursorType and / or CursorLocation properties, I don't know why though and I'm not familiar enough with those properties to be sure.